# The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 128 bytes. RSA DECRYPTION c#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, x509certificate

i do not know how to solve this exception while decrypting a file using private key from a X509 certificate.
"The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 128 bytes."

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("F:\\enc test\\file1.txt");
X509Certificate2 cer = new X509Certificate2(
    "E:\\fileManagementSrvc\\certificate\\cerpfx.pfx", "12345",
    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cer.PrivateKey;

byte[] d = rsa.Decrypt(data, false); //GETTING THE EXCEPTION HERE
string s = Encoding.Default.GetString(d);
```

Comment: What is exception message ? Could you share your errors ?

Comment: This is the exception message
CryptographicException

The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 128 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

RSA cannot encrypt data longer than modulus of RSA key. And if you use some kind of a padding, this value became even smaller.

Normally encryption of large data is performed with symmetric block ciphers like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) or [Triple-DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-DES) as they are faster than asymmetric ciphers such as RSA and designed to encrypt data longer than their key size. If you still want to use asymmetric encryption then encrypt AES/Tripple-DES key, which is shorter than 128 bytes with RSA at the end of the process.

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion:
[RSA Encrypt / Decrypt Problem in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475861/rsa-encrypt-decrypt-problem-in-net)
In short, there is indeed a fixed size for a message you can encrypt with rsa. Its not designed to encrypt the whole big file.